# Using Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am in the process of setting up data scraper that writes the data to an excel file and then I want to upload those files to a folder in my own drive account. This will be done once a day via a scheduler, so fully automated is the aim here.

I am looking at [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) quickstart guide and it goes through the process of Oauth2. I don't want to access any others user data, just push up the files i create. This may be a stupid question but do i have to go through the oAuth process and not just use an api key and secret for example?

In Step 4 it says `The first time you run the sample, it will prompt you to authorize access:`, how would i do that if this is running on an EC2 instance for example

Thanks

Comment: To quote [the docs page about authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth): *"Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported"*. You say you don't want to access user data, but that's what you're doing - it just happens to be your own user data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only going to be accessing your own account then you should look into a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  Service accounts are preauthorized so you wont get a window popping up asking for access.  I am not a node.js programer so i cant help much with code.  I dont see a service account example for node.js for google drive you may be able to find one for one of the other apis  or check the client library sample [examples](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples)

A service account is not you its a dummy user you can take the service account email address and share a folder or file on your personal google drive account with the service account and it will have access.  [read more about service accounts](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)

Answer (score 2):

I thought i would post how i got this to work (i need to look into checking if the file exists and then replace it, but that's later), firstly @DalmTo and @JoeClay had good points so i looked into them further and come across [this blog post](https://medium.com/@abhimanyuPathania/google-drive-service-accounts-and-nodejs-a038b8ec482f).

```
# index.js
const google = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./creds.json');
const drive = google.drive('v3');
const targetFolderId = "123456789"


const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  config.client_email,
  null,
  config.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
  null
);

jwtClient.authorize((authErr) => {
  if (authErr) {
    console.log(authErr);
    return;
  }


const fileMetadata = {
  name: './file.txt,
  parents: [targetFolderId]
};

const media = {
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
  body: fs.createReadStream('./file.txt' )
};

drive.files.create({
  auth: jwtClient,
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media,
  fields: 'id'
}, (err, file) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
    console.log('Uploaded File Id: ', file.data.id);
  });
});
```

As I said previously my next step is to check if the file exists and if it does replace it

Comment: You're missing the trailing single quote on the line below -
    name: './file.txt,